# Rendering interactive PDFs in IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios6, core-graphics

To render a PDF in Objective C we are calling `CGContextDrawPDFPage` method. In IOS6, interactive PDFs rendering using this method take large amounts of memory and it leads to memory warning after some time. This is because of the caching mechanism of moved pages inside the application. But the application is crashing due to memory warning. When I profile the application in IOS6 the memory is working perfectly in IOS5 and memory is stable. Anybody know about this issue? Are there any changes in PDF rendering(`CoreGraphics` & `QuartzCore`) frameworks in IOS6?